# Bluetooth mysteriously disappears from Windows 10 until computer restart

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, dell-xps

Randomly, bluetooth will stop working and disappear from device manager after I've shut my Dell XPS laptop running Windows 10. There's no way to "turn it on" and it doesn't show up anywhere in settings -- until I restart my computer. This ends up meaning that I have to restart my computer every few days just to get bluetooth back.

This has been ongoing for many months, and I've tried: updating Windows; updating drivers; uninstalling and reinstalling bluetooth-specific drivers.

Any thoughts on what might be causing this? Thanks!

Comment: I've tried: updating Windows; updating drivers;   .....  I use Bluetooth on two laptops here and always on and no loss. Perhaps try updating BIOS (UEFI) to see if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Since a restart seems to bring it back up, try disabling `Fast Startup` from your power settings. You can find the toggle under: `Control Panel >> Power Options >> Choose what the power buttons do`

You could also try disabling and re-enabling the Bluetooth device in the Device Manager to save yourself a restart.

But if the Bluetooth device doesn't appear in the Device Manager either, then it could be a physical issue with the card.